# Separar en partes un map ordenado nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, map, ordenamiento

Tengo el siguiente código

```
currency.sort((a, b) => b.balance - a.balance)
        .filter(user => message.client.users.cache.has(user.user_id) && !message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'admin'))
        .first(10)
        .map((user, position) => `**#${position + 1}** ${(message.client.users.cache.get(user.user_id).tag)}: ${user.balance}`)
        .join('\n');
```

El código ordena una lista de usuarios en base a quién tiene mas "monedas", y escoge los 10 primeros y los mapea para darle un formato. Hasta ahí todo bien.

El objetivo ahora es que en vez de guardar todos juntos, el primero con mas monedas, el segundo, los siguientes 4 y los últimos 4 formen parte de strings diferentes, ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? he probado varias cosas pero no he conseguido que funcione.

Comment: Cual es el sentido de hacerlo?, clasificacion?, porque te gustaria separar esta informacion?, si necesitas hacer tantos procesos algo me dice que estas haciendo algo mal... realmente ni yo transformando waypoints y acomodandolos hago tantos procesos, todo eso cabe en una sola linea.

Comment: Momento... dices... separar los ultimos cuatro?, has probado a usar `slice`?

Comment: Podrias mostrar el resultado que obtienes actualmente con este código? Y tambien dar un ejemplo del resultado que esperas obtener

Answer (score 0):

No podes hacerlo en una sola línea

deberías hacer

```javascript
const sortedArray = array.sort(...);

const primero = sortedArray[0];
const segundo = sortedArray[1];

const terceros = sortedArray.slice(2, 4);
const cuartos = sortedArray.slice(6, 4);
```